# How to Mock Member Objects in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking

I want to create a unit test environment for our project. But I am lost about how to create mocks for members of the classes. I want to explain my question with an example.

In my older projects, we were using a mock selection mechanism which is very ugly in my opinion. Here is the elder method:

```
class member {
};

class member_mock_1 {
};

class member_mock_2 {
};

class parent {
#if defined UNIT_TEST_1
  typedef member_t member_mock_1;
#elif defined UNIT_TEST_2
  typedef member_t member_mock_2;
#else
  typedef member_t member;
#endif

private:
  member_t mem;
};
```

The first question is mocking the classes of the member object with typedefing in or out of the parent class is a proper way or not? What is the best practice? If I want to use a unit testing framework, like gtest, should I use this kind of way or is there another way to mocking members?

Note 1: If the virtual mechanism is activated, it is ok to create base classes to ease mocking, if a class is pod or something, I don't want to use this mechanism.

Note 2: I also find ugly passing the types of members as a template parameter, everything becomes template in the project. I don't want to do that. Here is an example:

```
template <typename M>
class parent {
private:
  M mem;
};

#if defined UNIT_TEST_1
  typedef parent_t parent<member_mock_1>;
#elif defined UNIT_TEST_2
  typedef parent_t parent<member_mock_2>;
#else
  typedef parent_t parent<member>;
#endif
```

Here is the method i am suggesting here:

member_mock_1.hpp

```
class member_mock_1 {
};
```

member_mock_2.hpp

```
class member_mock_2 {
};
```

mock.hpp

```
template <typename TYPE>
struct mock { using type = TYPE; };

#define ENABLE_MOCKING(NamE) \
using NamE ## _t = mock<NamE>::type
```

member_mock.hpp

```
#if define UNIT_TEST_1
  template<>
  struct mock<member> { using type = member_mock_1 };
#endif

#if define UNIT_TEST_2
  template<>
  struct mock<member> { using type = member_mock_2 };
#endif
```

member.hpp

```
class member {
};

ENABLE_MOCKING(member);
```

parent.hpp

```
class parent {
private:
  member_t mem;
};
```

Method I have mentioned above works for normal classes. For template classes some extra works should be done, i think.

So as a conclusion, I am suggesting a structure for unit testing like above. May be it is unnecessary, there are some other mechanisms or ways to cover that requirement. Maybe I still reinventing the wheel :(

Please suggest a way you know for mocking members of a class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You're reinventing the wheel the code looks really messy:

```
#if defined UNIT_TEST_1
  typedef parent_t parent<member_mock_1>;
#elif defined UNIT_TEST_2
  typedef parent_t parent<member_mock_2>;
#else
  typedef parent_t parent<member>;
#endif
```

There are several tools available.
I use Typemock Isolator++ as you can mock pretty much everything without touching your production whatsoever.
One other thing, the behavior you set on a mock will be applied only in the scope of the test, so every test has an individual and independent setup.

You can access the member, even if it's private:

```
member* mock_member = FAKE<member>;
parent* my_parent = new parent();
ISOLATOR_SET_MEMBER(my_parent, mem, mock_member);
```

And easily get it:

```
member* get_member;
ISOLATOR_GET_MEMBER(my_parent, mem, get_member);
```

Also, it allows to fake abstract classes, global methods, pure virtual methods, private and protected methods, set up behaviors for it. Furthermore, access hidden data members and invoke them. Check [this](https://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Ipp&page=Documentation%2Fintroduction.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I am in a similar situation to you - introducing unit tests to a legacy C++ project. To do so I have used a lot of **preprocessor directives** along with [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest) and [Google Mock](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googlemock). Particularly, if I was facing to your example, I would do as follows:

```
#if defined UNIT_TEST
class imember
{
    virtual void a_method() = 0;
};
#endif

class member
#if defined UNIT_TEST
: public imember
#endif
{
    void a_method()
    {
        // do something
    };
};

class parent {
public:
#if defined UNIT_TEST
    parent(imember mem) : mem_(mem) {};
#endif

private:
#if defined UNIT_TEST
    imember mem_;
#else
    member mem_;
#endif
};
```

Now, use Google Mock to define a mock class:

```
class mockmember : public imember
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(a_method, void());
};
```

Mock class is now ready. Use Google Test to define your test scenarios:

```
class parenttest : public testing::Test
{
public:
    parenttest() : member_(mockmember()), parent_(member_) {}
    virtual void SetUp() {}
    virtual void TearDown() {}

protected:
    parent parent_;
    mockmember member_;
};

TEST_F(parenttest, a_func)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(member_, a_method());
    int ret = parent_.a_func();
    ASSERT_EQ(0, ret);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, i work in Typemock.

Sam is totally right.
Also, you don't need to create 3 different member_mock classes for every single unit-test.

You can simply set up the behavior, for example, for some private method in member:

```
member* mock_member = FAKE<member>;
PRIVATE_WHEN_CALLED(member, somePrivateMethod()).Return(0);
```

Next using `PRIVATE_WHEN_CALLED(mock_member, somePrivateMethod())` will overload behavior for somePrivateMethod(), so, instead of creating huge amount of different mock-classes just change the behavior for you needs.

Hope it'll be useful for you!